# Play json merge formats for case class with more than 22 fields

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I am trying to split format to multiple tuples so it can handle more than 22 fields in the case class. However, I got an error **"value and is not a member of play.api.libs.json.Format"**. How can I merge multiple formats for a case class?

```
val fields1to2: Format[(Int, String)] = (
  (__ \ "a").format[Int] and
  (__ \ "b").format[String]
).tupled

val fields3to4: Format[(Boolean, List[Int])] = (
  (__ \ "c").format[Boolean] and
  (__ \ "d").format[List[Int]]
).tupled

implicit val hugeCaseClassReads: Format[Huge] = (
  fields1to2 and fields3to4 // "value and is not a member of play.api.libs.json.Format"
) {
  case ((a, b), (c, d)) =>  
    Huge(a, b, c, d)
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you have any chance to do what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not limited to use only Play-JSON then try the [Play-Json extensions](https://github.com/xdotai/play-json-extensions) library:

```
import ai.x.play.json.Jsonx
implicit val hugeCaseClassReads: Format[Huge] = Jsonx.formatCaseClass
```

But a more handy, safe, and efficient option would be using of [jsoniter-scala](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala) - it has built in support of case classes with huge numbers of fields.

Answer (score 0):

Adding these imports solved the issue for me. In your case just importing the first one should solve the issue.

```
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

import play.api.libs.json.{Json, Reads, _}
```